# VBA Excel automatic colour and value change

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to set up a personal management spreadsheet for work.  I have a list of tasks with varying priority.

What I am trying to do here is if the number of tasks * priority goes hits certain thresholds the colour of the availability cells changes and the description cell value changes, eg "busy"

here is the code I have so far, how do I implement it to change automatically when I change the value of the task list

```
Sub Avail_flag()

TasksRange = ActiveSheet.Range("P3:P6")
availcells = Range("M8,N8")
busyflag = 0
medBusyFlag = 0
highBusyFlag = 0
imedBusyFlag = 0

If Range("p4") > 0 Then
    medBusyFlag = 1
ElseIf Range("p4") > 2 Then
    medBusyFlag = 2
ElseIf Range("p5") > 0 Then
    highBusyFlag = 1
ElseIf Range("p5") > 2 Then
    highBusyFlag = 2
ElseIf Range("p6") > 0 Then
    imedBusyFlag = 1
End If

For Each sell In lRange
    busyflag = (medBusyFlag + (highBusyFlagI * 2) + (imedBusyFlag * 3))

    If busyflag > 0 Then
        For Each cell In Range(availcells)
            cell.Color = green
        Next
        cell("N8").Value = "Occupied"
    ElseIf busyflag > 3 Then
        For Each cell In Range(availcells)
            cell.Color = orange
        Next
        cell("N8").Value = "Busy"
    ElseIf busyflag > 5 Then
        For Each cell In Range(availcells)
            cell.Color = red
        Next
        cell("N8").Value = "Unavailable"
    Else
        For Each cell In Range(availcells)
            cell.Color = white

    End If


End Sub
```

here is a capture of the spreadsheet if that helps, the highlighted grey part is where all the magic happens

[image]

Comment: why not use Conditional Formatting?

Comment: Have a look at the Worksheet object module, there are event procedures that fire off when a cell's value changes. This is where you want to copy your code to

Comment: Can you change a cell value with conditional formatting? for the busy/available/unavailable change?

Comment: you could use CF + `If` formula for cell `N5`. Or if you need only VBA, use `worksheet_change` event for your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Change` event for the sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
```

Answer (score 0):

I went for conditional formatting, something I hadn't heard of before.  After looking it up and learning how to use it it seem to be by far the best option.  Thank you @mehow for the usggestion